# $W_3$ algebra conformal block at level 1

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory, representation-theory

I'm in the process of learning CFT theory, and I'm trying to reproduce the known result of the calculation of the $W_3$ algebra conformal block at level 1 given in Appendix A.2 of the paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2189

The conformal block as defined in this paper is
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\sum_{\textbf{(k,l)},\textbf{(k',l')}}\left\langle \alpha_1| V_{\alpha_2}(1)|\psi_{\textbf{(k,l)}}(\alpha)\right\rangle\,\left(K\right)^{-1}\,\left\langle \psi_{\textbf{(k',l')}}(\alpha)|V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\right\rangle}{\left\langle \alpha_1|V_{\alpha_2}(1)|\alpha \right\rangle \,\left\langle \alpha|V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\right\rangle}
\end{eqnarray}

where the sum is over the intermediate states $\psi_{\textbf{(k,l)}}(\alpha)$ of the form

$\psi_{(\textbf{k,l)}}(\alpha)=L_{-\textbf{k}}W_{-\textbf{l}}|\alpha\rangle,$

and $K$ is the Gram matrix
$K=\langle\psi_{(\textbf{k,l)}}(\alpha)|\psi_{(\textbf{k',l')}}(\alpha) \rangle$.

At level 1, there are two states:

\begin{eqnarray}
|\psi_1\rangle &=& L_{-1}|\alpha\rangle, \\ |\psi_2\rangle &=& \left[W_{-1}-\frac{3w_\alpha}{2\Delta_\alpha}L_{-1} \right]|\alpha\rangle
\end{eqnarray}

so $K$ is the Gram matrix given below
\begin{eqnarray}
K = \begin{pmatrix} \langle \psi_1|\psi_1\rangle\ &  \langle \psi_1|\psi_2\rangle\\\
 \langle \psi_2|\psi_1\rangle&  \langle \psi_2|\psi_2\rangle\end{pmatrix}
 =\begin{pmatrix} 
 2\Delta_\alpha & 0\\
 0 & \Delta_\alpha \left[ \frac{32}{22+5c}\left(\Delta_\alpha + \frac{1}{5}\right)-\frac{1}{5}\right]-\frac{9}{2}\frac{w^2_\alpha}{\Delta_\alpha}
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

The level 1 conformal block is a sum over 4 terms $(i,j)$ with $i,j=1,2$ but it receives contribution only from the $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ components, i.e.
\begin{eqnarray}
\underbrace{\frac{\left\langle \alpha_1| V_{\alpha_2}(1)|\psi_1(\alpha)\right\rangle\,\left(K_{11}\right)^{-1}\,\left\langle \psi_1(\alpha)|V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\right\rangle}{\left\langle \alpha_1|V_{\alpha_2}(1)|\alpha \right\rangle \,\left\langle \alpha|V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\right\rangle}}_{\text{Virasoro conformal block at level 1}}
 + \underbrace{\frac{\left\langle \alpha_1| V_{\alpha_2}(1)|\psi_2(\alpha)\right\rangle\,\left(K_{22}\right)^{-1}\,\left\langle \psi_2(\alpha)|V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\right\rangle}{\left\langle \alpha_1|V_{\alpha_2}(1)|\alpha \right\rangle \,\left\langle \alpha|V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\right\rangle}}_\text{To be calculated}
\end{eqnarray}

The first term in the sum above is just the Virasoro conformal block at level 1, whose explicit expression is
\begin{eqnarray}
z \frac{\left(\Delta(\alpha)+\Delta(\alpha_2)-\Delta(\alpha_1)\right)\left( \Delta(\alpha)+\Delta(\alpha_3) - \Delta(\alpha_4)\right)}{2\Delta(\alpha)}
\end{eqnarray}
It remains to calculate the second term involving $(K_{22})^{-1}$. Here is where I encounter some difficulty and I suspect that I have made some basic mistakes. The steps I took are as follows.

1. Using the explicit form of $|\psi_2(\alpha)\rangle$, we have
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \frac{\left\langle \alpha_1\left| V_{\alpha_2}(1)\left[W_{-1}-\frac{3w_\alpha}{2\Delta_\alpha}L_{-1} \right]\right|\alpha\right\rangle\,\left(K_{22}\right)^{-1}\,\left\langle\alpha\left| \left[W_{1}-\frac{3w_\alpha}{2\Delta_\alpha}L_{1} \right]V_{\alpha_3}(z)\right|\alpha_4\right\rangle}{\left\langle \alpha_1|V_{\alpha_2}(1)|\alpha \right\rangle \,\left\langle \alpha|V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\right\rangle}
   \end{eqnarray}

which can be broken down into the following sum
\begin{eqnarray}
(\text{$W_3$ numerator sum})&=&\langle \alpha_1|V_{\alpha_2}(1)W_{-1}|\alpha\rangle \langle \alpha|W_1 V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\rangle - \frac{3w_\alpha}{2\Delta_\alpha} \langle \alpha_1 |V_{\alpha_2}(1)W_{-1}|\alpha\rangle\langle \alpha|L_1 V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\rangle
\\
&& - \frac{3w_\alpha}{2\Delta_\alpha} \langle \alpha_1| V_{\alpha_2}(1)L_{-1}|\alpha\rangle \langle \alpha|W_1 V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\rangle + \frac{9w^2_\alpha}{4\Delta^2_\alpha} \langle \alpha_1| V_{\alpha_2}(1)L_{-1}|\alpha\rangle \langle \alpha|L_1 V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\rangle \label{w3-terms}
\end{eqnarray}

multiplied by the factor
\begin{eqnarray}
(\text{$W_3$ prefactor})=\frac{(K_{22})^{-1}}{\langle \alpha_1|V_{\alpha_2}(1)|\alpha\rangle \,\langle \alpha|V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\rangle}.
\end{eqnarray}

2. Next, I want to write all the terms involving the operator insertions in the 3-point functions in terms of the 3-point functions of the primaries only. For those terms involving only the $L_1, L_{-1}$ operators, this is straightforward, by using the formula
   \begin{eqnarray}\label{eq:LmV}
   [ L_m, V_\alpha] = 
    z^m\left\{(m+1)\Delta_\alpha V_\alpha + z(L_{-1}V_\alpha)\right\} 
   \end{eqnarray}
   which, upon substituting $m=0$ in the original formula above and rewrite $ z(L_{-1}V_\alpha)$ in terms of $[L_0, V_\alpha]$, is equivalent to
   \begin{eqnarray}
   [ L_m, V_\alpha] = z^m\left\{ m \,\Delta_\alpha V_\alpha + [L_0, V_\alpha]\right\}.
   \end{eqnarray}
   This latter formula allows us to obtain the following terms straightforwardly:
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \langle \alpha_1|V_{\alpha_2}(1) L_{-1}|\alpha \rangle &=& \left(\Delta(\alpha_2)-\Delta(\alpha_1) +\Delta(\alpha)\right)\left\langle \alpha_1|V_{\alpha_2}(1)|\alpha\right\rangle
   \\
   \left\langle \alpha|L_1 V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\right\rangle &=& z \left(\Delta(\alpha_3) +\Delta(\alpha)-\Delta(\alpha_4)\right)\left\langle \alpha|V_{\alpha_3} |\alpha_4\right\rangle
   \end{eqnarray}
   For the terms involving the $W_{-1}, W_{1}$ insertions, I made use of the following formula
   \begin{eqnarray}
   [ W_m, V_\alpha] =z^m \left[ \frac{m(m+2)}{2}w_\alpha V_\alpha + z m(W_{-1}V_\alpha) +[ W_0, V_\alpha] \right]
   \end{eqnarray}
   which is obtained from the original formula
   \begin{eqnarray}
   [ W_m, V_\alpha] = z^m \left[ \frac{(m+1)(m+2)}{2}w_\alpha V_\alpha + z(m+1)(W_{-1}V_\alpha) + z^2(W_{-2}V_\alpha)\right]
   \label{W-pr}
   \end{eqnarray}
   by letting $m=0$ and substituting $z(m+1)(W_{-1}V_\alpha) + z^2(W_{-2}V_\alpha)$ by a term involving $W_0$. This allows me to obtain
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \left\langle \alpha_1|V_{\alpha_2}(1)W_{-1}|\alpha\right\rangle &=& \left(-w_{\alpha_1} + w_\alpha +\frac{1}{2}w_{\alpha_2}\right)\left\langle \alpha_1V_{\alpha_2}(1)|\alpha\right\rangle
   \\
   \left\langle \alpha|W_1V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\right\rangle &=&z\left( \frac{3}{2}w_{\alpha_3} + w_\alpha -w_{\alpha_4}\right)\left\langle \alpha | V_{\alpha_3}(z)| \alpha_4 \right\rangle
   \end{eqnarray}
3. Substituting the 4 terms involving the operator insertions $W_{\pm 1}, L_{\pm 1}$ into the ($W_3$ numerator sum) equation gives
   \begin{eqnarray}
   &&z\left\{\left(\frac{w_{\alpha_2}}{2}-w_{\alpha_1}+w_\alpha\right)\left(\frac{3w_{\alpha_3}}{2} + w_\alpha -w_{\alpha_4}\right)
   -\frac{3w_\alpha}{\Delta_\alpha}\left(\frac{w_{\alpha_2}}{2}-w_{\alpha_1}+w_\alpha \right)\left(\Delta_{\alpha_3}+\Delta_\alpha -\Delta_{\alpha_4} \right)\right.
   \\
   &&
   \left.\,\,\,-\frac{3w_\alpha}{2\Delta_\alpha} \left( \Delta_{\alpha_2}-\Delta_{\alpha_1}+\Delta_\alpha\right)\left( \frac{3w_{\alpha_3}}{2}+w_\alpha -w_{\alpha_4}\right)
   +\frac{9w^2_\alpha}{4\Delta^2_\alpha}\left(\Delta_{\alpha_2}-\Delta_{\alpha_1}+\Delta_\alpha \right)\left(\Delta_{\alpha_3}+\Delta_\alpha -\Delta_{\alpha_4}\right)
   \right\}
   \\
   &&\,\,\,\times \left\langle\alpha_1|V_{\alpha_2}(1)|\alpha\right\rangle \left\langle \alpha|V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\right\rangle.
   \end{eqnarray}

which, when combined with the $W_3$ prefactor gives
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{(\Delta_\alpha(2 w_{\alpha_1}-w_{\alpha_2})+w_\alpha(-3 \Delta_{\alpha_1}+3 \Delta_{\alpha_2}+\Delta_{\alpha})) (-3 \Delta_\alpha w_{\alpha_3}+2 \Delta_\alpha w_{\alpha_4}+w_\alpha(3 \Delta_{\alpha_3}-3 \Delta_{\alpha_4}+\Delta_{\alpha}))}{4 \Delta_{\alpha}^2} 
\nonumber\\
&&\times\left[ \Delta_\alpha \left[ \frac{32}{22+5c}\left(\Delta_\alpha + \frac{1}{5}\right)-\frac{1}{5}\right]-\frac{9}{2}\frac{w^2_\alpha}{\Delta_\alpha}\right]^{-1}
\end{eqnarray}
This is not correct, because the correct answer is given in Eq.A.14 of 0907.2189v2 as:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\left[\frac{w_{\alpha_2}}{2}-\frac{w_{\alpha}}{2}-w_{\alpha_1}+\frac{3}{2} \left(-\frac{\Delta_{\alpha_1} w_{\alpha_2}}{\Delta_{\alpha_2}}+\frac{\Delta_{\alpha} w_{\alpha_2}}{\Delta_{\alpha_2}}+\frac{\Delta_{\alpha_1} w_{\alpha}}{\Delta_{\alpha}}-\frac{\Delta_{\alpha_2} w_{\alpha}}{\Delta_{\alpha}}\right)\right] 
\nonumber\\
&&\times\left[\frac{w_{\alpha_3}}{2}-\frac{w_{\alpha}}{2}-w_{\alpha_4}+\frac{3}{2} \left(-\frac{\Delta_{\alpha_4} w_{\alpha_3}}{\Delta_{\alpha_3}}+\frac{\Delta_{\alpha} w_{\alpha_3}}{\Delta_{\alpha_3}}-\frac{\Delta_{\alpha_3} w_{\alpha}}{\Delta_{\alpha}}+\frac{\Delta_{\alpha_4} w_{\alpha}}{\Delta_{\alpha}}\right)\right]
\nonumber\\
&&\times\left[ \Delta_\alpha \left[ \frac{32}{22+5c}\left(\Delta_\alpha + \frac{1}{5}\right)-\frac{1}{5}\right]-\frac{9}{2}\frac{w^2_\alpha}{\Delta_\alpha}\right]^{-1}
\end{eqnarray}

I don't know what went wrong in my calculations above, and I'd be grateful if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I've realized the mistake I made in the above calculations. The problem lies in the application of the formula:
\begin{eqnarray}
\left[ W_m, V_\alpha\right] &=&
z^m \left[ \frac{m(m+3)}{2}w_\alpha V_\alpha + z m(W_{-1}V_\alpha) +\left[ W_0, V_\alpha\right] \right] \label{W-pr3}
\end{eqnarray}
in the 3-point functions $\langle \alpha_1|V_{\alpha_2} W_{-1}|\alpha\rangle$ and $\langle \alpha|W_1V_{\alpha_3}|\alpha_4\rangle$. Before applying the above formula, one must make use of the null vector condition
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(W_{-1}-\frac{3w_\alpha}{2\Delta_\alpha}L_{-1} \right)|\alpha\rangle =0 \,\,\Rightarrow\,\,W_{-1}V_\alpha=\frac{3w_\alpha}{2\Delta_\alpha}L_{-1}V_\alpha = \frac{3w_\alpha}{2\Delta_\alpha}z^{-1}\left( [L_0, V_\alpha]- \Delta_\alpha V_\alpha\right)
\end{eqnarray}
This means that
\begin{eqnarray}
\left[ W_m, V_\alpha\right] &=&
z^m \left[ \frac{m^2}{2}w_\alpha V_\alpha + \frac{3w_\alpha}{2\Delta_\alpha} m[L_0,V_\alpha] +\left[ W_0, V_\alpha\right] \right]. 
\end{eqnarray}
Applying the above equation in the 3-point functions $\langle \alpha_1|V_{\alpha_2} W_{-1}|\alpha\rangle$ and $\langle \alpha|W_1V_{\alpha_3}|\alpha_4\rangle$ gives

\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \alpha_1|V_{\alpha_2}(1)W_{-1}|\alpha\rangle &=& 
-\left(\frac{w_{\alpha_2}}{2} - \frac{3w_{\alpha_2}}{\Delta_{\alpha_2}}(\Delta_{\alpha_1} - \Delta_{\alpha}) + w_{\alpha_1} -w_\alpha\right)\langle \alpha_1|V_{\alpha_2}(1)|\alpha\rangle
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \alpha |W_1V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\rangle&=& \left( \frac{w_{\alpha_3}}{2} + \frac{3w_{\alpha_3}}{2\Delta_{\alpha_3}}\left( \Delta_\alpha - \Delta_{\alpha_4}\right) + w_{\alpha} -w_{\alpha_4}\right) \langle \alpha|V_{\alpha_3}(z)|\alpha_4\rangle
\end{eqnarray}

Combining these results with the inverse Kac matrix factor and the Virasoro term, I got a final result that is very close to the correct answer, (save for a sign error in one of the terms) that I still haven't managed to trace.